# Forced to use jQuery instead of $

Tags: jquery

I'm was doing my page with jquery scripting all of then written like `$.` , `$(`
My sample code like here

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

function dome(){
  $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'test.php',
     success: function(data) {
     alert('ok');
     }
});
}
```

But I also have to use a Prototype library, then after add code `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>`

My above function did not work any longer 
The error report from firebug is **TypeError: $.ajax is not a function**
Then only way to solve this is to change `$.ajax({` to `jQuery.ajax({`

Do you know how can I manage to do coding as short like I did before ($.)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `$` in your code to use it; `jQuery.noConflict();` will also do the trick.
Check the Internet on how to set `$` as a jQuery operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    (function($){ // remap '$' to jQuery

       $(function(){  // DOM ready
           // YOUR STUFF HERE
       });

    })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Or take a look at [jQuery.noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)  *From the docs:*

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery.noConflict(); in your code.

read here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: but this will free up $ for other libraries to use, you can't use $ for jQuery after this, OP wants to use $ for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Assign something else to Jquery like

```
var $_ = jQuery
```

then use `$_.ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.noConflict();` is the exact thing you're looking for to separate library uses.
[See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Just [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), man. They have examples and everything.